# Upgrading Apache from 2.2.X to 2.4.X.

Tags: fedora, php5, apache-2.4

I have just upgraded my fedora 17 to 18. So my apache server got updated in 2.4. Now I'm having trouble to configure apche since many things got modified in 2.4 from 2.2. Can please anyone suggest me some good documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the Apache manual? You should really be doing that *before* you come here, so you can ask us *specific, answerable questions* about *specific* problems you're encountering...

Answer (score 4):

I think the *BEST* documentation is from Apache itself:
[Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2 - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) (thanks to: ceejayoz). Also for reference, here is links for apache's full documentations:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

Comment: In particular, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: This documentation is horrible, it does not even mention breaking changes.